# how to redirect wordpress posts to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i need to redirect all posts from the old wordpress to a subdomain

ex:

old-domain/category/photos should redirect to new-domain/category/photos

but if old-domain/ only this should not redirect to the new url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of `old-domain`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
# not assets e.g images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|gif|jpe?g|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://new-domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Edit: modified rule so everything except the home page is redirected

Comment: thanks but not only category/photos, the idea is if theres is a parameter passed in it should redirect to the new domain if none stay in the old domain

Comment: If you mean redirect everything but the home page, then edited code above to do this. If you mean something else please provide more details and/or some examples. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ulrich that works, one more the assets like images,css on the old domain also redirects to the new domain